# about db2 log file archive and cleanup

Tags: logging, db2, resource-cleanup

I would like to start planning some disk cleanup for the machine where my db2 server is running now but it is not 100% clear how db2  might be affected when it comes to remove log files.

The configuration parameters for my db of interest says

```
Path To Log Files                          = /url_folder_log               
First log archive method (LOGARCHMETH1)    = DISK:/url_folder_arch
Log retain for recovery enable (LOGRETAIN) = OFF
Second log archive method   (LOGARCHMETH2) = OFF
User exit for logging enabled   (USEREXIT) = OFF
```

where `/url_folder_arch` is eating all the hard disk space.

As far as I understood (please correct me if I am wrong) db2 is backing up (better to say 'archiving') log files from `/url_folder_log/` into `/url_folder_arch` while it is running and in background.

I am tempted to move the majority of oldest log files from `/url_folder_arch` to some backup storage: is it safe to do that?

When are these 'archive log files' are really used and might be necessary?

Reading it seems that logs are involved in 2 processes

- database backup
- rollforward recovery (for which my db seems NOT enabled).

If this is the case do I really need to keep all of those archive log files?
At some point it might have the necessity also to delete these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your disaster recovery strategy. For example, some companies should have:

- a full backup of each semester, and they are never deleted.
- a monthly full backup of the last 12 months.
- the backups and archive logs of the last 3 months in tape or secondary storage.
- the backups and archive logs of the last month in disk.

According to a schema like this, you could know when you can delete the archive files. Remember that the archive logs allows you to recover the database to any point in time.

Having the archive logs in disk allows you to recover the database at any moment if you have a crash. And you do not restore to stage the files from secondary to primary storage.

Remember, if you perform a full backup, and there were operations during the backup, you should need some archive logs to start the database. It is always a good idea to test the backup for history when you are going to delete the archive logs. If a database after being restored needs archive logs, and you do not have them, the backup file is useless.

P.D. It is a good idea to have old backups, for example when you are going to incorporate a data warehouse, and you need to analyze the evolution of the data.

Comment: Thanks for your respone. I do agree though I need a small confirm as I read through lot of docs today. If I understood correctly once I 've done a backup (i.e. I can restore my backup) I can  remove (PRUNE) old log files as I can use that backup as a snapshot of the db in a point of time. If I want more I can use log that follow in time by means of rollforward. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But remember, that in that case the backups are "version backups", and you cannot roll forward for a specific point different of the backup. You can only restore a database to the date when the backup was performed.

Comment: really!? I thought that with rollforward I can use a backup + log for transactions after it. This given that LOG ARCHIVE 1 has been set i.e. given that "Archive Logs" is active instead of Circular one .

Comment: P.S. off course if my backup is corrupt I need to use previous log + previous backup (suppose I understood correctly).

Comment: What i meant is backup file for version backup. Rollfoward for log files (included in the backup file, archived or online). Depending on which files are available,  you can restore until a given point.